Possible to vote to close questions with active bounties
Over on RPG, I was able to close vote this question after it had a bounty posted:

As you can see, it currently has two close votes. And I did some testing right here on meta (shout out to Journeyman Geek for posting the bounty):

My vote has been recorded. Seeing that it wasn’t localized to RPG, I went to fitness where I’ve got the secret sauce and actually closed a bountied question, where it retained the bounty while closed:

The bounty FAQ states:

What happens if a question with an active bounty is closed or deleted? / Why can't I vote to close or migrate a question with an active bounty?
Questions with an active bounty cannot be closed or deleted directly.

Is this change in behavior intentional, or a bug?

The change is intentional: Bountied questions can now be close-voted: "Allow bountied questions to be closed by regular users". Bounties are now considered orthogonal.

Typical for SE, major change coming just like that without any notice, and they let people wonder and post bug reports. Same way they might change their mind tomorrow and revert it without telling anyone. (Because they saw someone request it, or just on a whim.)

@Slate It would be very nice if you tagged the feature request here on this site as completed and post an answer referring back to the MSO answer.

@Sonic Sure, can do. It's the end of the work day for me, though, so I'm forwarding any comment replies I get directly to your inbox ;)
